# fail to install adobe brackets on my win8.1

Tags: installation, adobe, adobe-brackets

I wanna install Adobe Brackets on my Windows 8.1 PC. But when it come to the installation directory , no matter where I choose, it keeps poping up a dialog that tells me "Installation directory must be on a local hard drive". Don't know why. Even the default directory C:\program file(x86)\Brackets\ is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jd1zCyr8nY0

Just execute at cmd (as admin):

```
msiexec /i "Path\To\Installer\Brackets.Release.1.0.msi"
```

Replace `Path\To\Installer` with your own path.

Comment: Not working. this command should be doing the same as double click the msi file. Funny thing is, I just tried to install again. the path part passed. but after clicking "Install". it tells me "Error reading from file xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.msi. Verify the file exists and that you can access it". do you happen to know what this means ?

Comment: And sometimes when I install from a msi file. I got error code 2755. Don't know why either. Never happened when i was using windows 7. some said it's about authority. but I checked and I'm sure i have access to it. Weird.

Comment: Hey bro @Lucas, found the solution. User SYSTEM does have access to the msi file. Need to add it and give it authority of 'read' and 'read and execute'. then everything works. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

copy the installer to the root of C:

Answer (score 0):

Try making this your MSI command you type in:

msiexec /i "Path\To\Installer\Brackets.Release.1.0.msi" WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH="1"

Caveat - You must TYPE IN the path you wish to install to fully.

If you try and change it change the Change Folder dialog you will get the error "installation directory must be a local hard drive"

This is a WiX bug and is scheduled to be fixed in WiX 4.0 -  https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4737

Healy